# How to find certain words in string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, search

I have an array of strings and each string contains a key word plus a number (the number value is different, only the key word is constant) and I want to know how can I get the word and also the number...see the example below:

```
var keyWords = ["data","action","type"];

var stringArray = ["set data4 to custom value '1'",
                   "set data110 to custom value '2'",
                   "overwrite value of action1023 with new value",
                   "set type23 to custom value '10'",
                   "overwrite value of action13 with text",
                   "set type48 to custom value '7'"]
```

And the response should be like this:

```
var response = ["data4","data110","action13","type23","action1023","type48"];
```

This is what I've managed to do:

```
  var response = [];
  for(var j=0; j<keyWords.length; j++) {
    for(var i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++) {
      if(stringArray[i].indexOf(keyWords[j]) !== -1) {
        response.push(keyWords[j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

But it only returns me the exact key words, without numbers..

```
response = [data, data, action, action, type, type]
```

Comment: I just only managed to get the keyWords from array, but without the numbers...

Comment: Use regular expressions http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: @Typo I'll try to implement the solution using a regular expression, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does the job

```
var keyWords = ["data","action","value","type"];

var stringArray = ["set data4 to custom value '1'",
               "set data110 to custom value '2'",
               "overwrite value of action1023 with new value",
               "set type23 to custom value '10'",
               "overwrite value of action13 with text",
               "set type48 to custom value '7'"]

var response = [];

for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; ++i){
    for(var j = 0; j < keyWords.length; ++j){
        if((index = stringArray[i].indexOf(keyWords[j])) !== -1){
            splittedStr = stringArray[i].substring(index,         stringArray[i].length).split(' ', 1);
            response.push(splittedStr[0]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to take the regex approach,

this example might be what you were looking for:

```
var found = [],
    result;   

for(var i in stringArray){
   result = stringArray[i].match(/(data|action|value|type)(\d+)/);
   found.push(result);
}
```

in the *"found"* array you should get a list of items, each with the following data:

1. the original keyword match (the keyword string with the number)
2. the keyword string part (without the number)
3. the number only (extracted from the keyword)

An example output:

```
[["data4", "data", "4"], ["data110", "data", "110"], ["action1023", "action", "1023"], ["type23", "type", "23"], ["action13", "action", "13"], ["type48", "type", "48"]]
```

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: You should use `\d+` instead of `\d*` for the number to avoid match other occurences of the keywords (e.g. "override the **value** of ...")

Comment: You may want to update the output as well :) `["value", "value", ""]` is not part of it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Very straightforward approach:

```js
var keyWords = ["data","action","value","type"];

var stringArray = ["set data4 to custom value '1'",
                   "set data110 to custom value '2'",
                   "overwrite value of action1023 with new value",
                   "set type23 to custom value '10'",
                   "overwrite value of action13 with text",
                   "set type48 to custom value '7'"]

function f(keyWords, stringArray){
 let output = []
 
 stringArray.forEach((sentence) => {
  var words = sentence.split(' ')
 
  words.forEach((word) => {
   keyWords.forEach((keyword) => {   
    if(word.indexOf(keyword) > -1 ) {
     output.push(word)
    }    
   })
  })
 })
  
 return output
}

console.log(f(keyWords, stringArray))
```

Comment: It doesn't return words that contains "action"

Comment: Fixed, I thought only first matches were needed.

Answer (score 0):

... a more generic and functional approach ...

```js
var
    keyList       = ["data", "action", "value", "type"],

    sentenceList  = [
        "set data4 to custom value '1'",
        "set data110 to custom value '2'",
        "overwrite value of action1023 with new value",
        "set type23 to custom value '10'",
        "overwrite value of action13 with text",
        "set type48 to custom value '7'"
    ],

    wordList = sentenceList.reduce(function collectSpecificWords (collector, sentence) {
        var
            matchList = sentence.split(/\s+/).filter(function (word) {

                return collector.regXWord.test(word);
            });

        collector.wordList = collector.wordList.concat(matchList);

        return collector;

    }, {

      //regXWord: RegExp("^("+ keyList.join("|") + ")[0-9]+$"),
        regXWord: RegExp("^("+ keyList.join("|") + ")[0-9]*$"),
        wordList: []

    }).wordList;


console.log("wordList : ", wordList);
```